# What is this type of switch called?

Tags: switches, identification

What would I search for to find some information about this sort of switch and/or a replacement?

It's just two copper strips embedded in an insulator that get mashed together by a button.  It says 'JX-10' on it but that doesn't seem to help my search.

It sits in the base of an electrical heater resting on a plastic peg.  The peg rests on the floor and the weight of the heater pushes down on it closing the contacts.  If the heater falls over, the contacts separate automatically.

[image: The switch I'm trying to identify]

Comment: Looks like a thermostat to me.

Comment: It's in a heater but that's not what it's being used for!  Added some description of where it is used.

Comment: It looks like a broken switch to me... But seriously, it may well be custom if it is from a mass produced product.

Comment: @trevor, I guess casting some insulator and sticking some copper in isn't exactly rocket science;  it is broken.

Comment: It's basically a push-to-make, spring release button similar to a doorbell but probably with longer stroke and softer spring. There is no sign of toggle action in it so it will probably arc when opening slowly under load.